# I want to ask the user to input an integer and check it and return an error message if it isn't in R

Tags: r

now I thought I would simply use is.integer and use the TRUE or FALSE output as a condition for my error message, but it seems even integers give FALSE cause R stores them float or something (e.g. 5) but if I change the input to as.integer then all inputs become integers thus defeating the purpose of the program.

num = readline(prompt = "Enter a number: ")

y = num

x <- is.integer(num)

if (y > 0 && x == FALSE) {

print("Please enter a natural number")

}

Comment: We need some details about 1) how you ask users for input (`readline`?) as some functions may return a character vector even if the input is an integer and 2) some input that you pass to it. For example, check the difference between `is.integer(1)` and `is.integer(1L)`, and `is.integer("1L")`. Also, there is a note in the help page - *`is.integer(x)` does not test if x contains integer numbers*

Comment: num = readline(prompt = "Enter a number: ")//

y = num//

x <- is.integer(num)//

if (y > 0 && x == FALSE) {//

  print("Please enter a natural number")//

}//  (the // are to show that its the start of a new line)

Comment: Check using `x <- as.numeric(num); !is.na(x) && x == round(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

`readline` stores user input as a character. You can use `as.numeric()` for your case. Input will become `NA` if it cannot be converted to numeric. Integrality can be tested using `round(num) != num`.

```
num <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter a number: "))

if (is.na(num) | num <= 0 | round(num) != num) {
  
  print("Please enter a natural number")
  
}
```

Comment: Yes as.integer will just convert what ever input into an integer but I finally figured it out as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter a number: "))

Comment: @user2554330 You are right. Updated the answer.